# UV Project messes up UV map

Tags: texturing, materials, modifiers, uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to animate eyes using the UV Project modifier, but when I enter the empty I want controlling the modifier, the UV is messed up.

Here is the mesh before I apply the UV Project modifier:
[image]

And here is the mesh after the modifier is applied:
[image]

I've tried editing the UV map and moving the empty to see if it's just in the wrong place but I can't stop the texture from looking distorted. Any suggestions?

Comment: hello, could you please pack your image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots How do I share a file?

Comment: read the instructions of the page I've linked, or use: https://pasteall.org/blend/ Don't forget to pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend)

Comment: @moonboots. Here it is: https://pasteall.org/blend/2736976f273242b4ac46f718026d1a1d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Bring back the scale of your empty to 1 with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
- Rotate it 90° on the X axis
- In the *Image Texture* node, switch from *Clip* to *Extend*
- Scale the empty as much as needed in order to have the scale you want for you image

[image]